# Marginalia / Docco / etc for Java Maven projects?

Tags: java, maven, literate-programming, docco, marginalia

Is it possible to run [Marginalia](https://github.com/fogus/marginalia) on a Java (multi-module) project which uses Maven?

Or is there any other alternative that's similar to Marginalia or [Docco](http://jashkenas.github.com/docco/) that can do this?

What's important to me is to be able to add it as a dependency from some public Maven repository and to use it straight away, without installing any additional stuff like Node.js for Docco for example - which is reasonable since it's a Java project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried several options:

- Marginalia with the Zi plugin;
- [Jocco](https://github.com/Krilivye/Jocco) (though it is not published on any Maven repo);
- and then, I found [atlasssian-docco](https://bitbucket.org/doklovic_atlassian/atlassian-docco/wiki)!

I'll have to revise my comments formatting to fit the [guide](https://bitbucket.org/doklovic_atlassian/atlassian-docco/wiki/writing-docco-comments), but I think this Maven plugin will do the job. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If people are still searching for an alternative programming Documentation Generator to javadoc. I have tried Atlassian Docco, but the generated doc is not so appealing and readable. Then found out [Groc](http://nevir.github.io/groc/). As of now far better than former. Groc aims to support [Literate Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming). Give it a try. Seems like Groc does not contain Maven dependency

Answer (score 0):

[docufier](https://github.com/programmiersportgruppe/docufier) is a tool that turns classes with doc comments (e.g. unit tests) into markdown. There is also a maven plugin.

An example would be the following test case:

```
/**
 *
 * Output and Input
 * ----------------
 *
 * For more control over the execution we'll use a `ProcBuilder` instance to configure
 * the process.
 *
 * The run method builds and spawns the actual process and blocks until the process exits.
 * The process takes care of writing the output to a stream, as opposed to the standard
 * facilities in the JDK that expect the client to actively consume the
 * output from an input stream:
 */
@Test
public void testOutputToStream() {
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    new ProcBuilder("echo")
        .withArg("Hello World!")
        .withOutputStream(output)
        .run();

    assertEquals("Hello World!\n", output.toString());
}
```

Which will be rendered to the following markdown:

```
Output and Input
----------------

For more control over the execution we'll use a `ProcBuilder` instance to configure
the process.

The run method builds and spawns the actual process and blocks until the process exits.
The process takes care of writing the output to a stream, as opposed to the standard
facilities in the JDK that expect the client to actively consume the
output from an input stream:

~~~ .java
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

new ProcBuilder("echo")
    .withArg("Hello World!")
    .withOutputStream(output)
    .run();

assertEquals("Hello World!\n", output.toString());
~~~
```

For a full example refer to the [README.md](https://github.com/fleipold/jproc/blob/master/README.md) of the jproc project, which has been generated from the [acceptance test suite](https://github.com/fleipold/jproc/blob/master/src/test/java/org/buildobjects/process/ProcBuilderTest.java).